# How to add buttons to a new tkinter window in Python/Spyder?

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I am trying to create a program in Spyder that uses tkinter, everything is working as planned, however, I am having a problem getting my calculator buttons to show in by calculator window. The buttons do work as I have tried them in the root/home screen but when I try to add them to my calculator window i get the error "name 'calcWindow' is not defined" pops up when I execute the program, if anybody would be able to nudge me in the right direction to be able to fix this I would be extremely grateful.

My code will be shown below.

```
    from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()#Creates root widget 
root.title("Welcome Screen")#Names the welcome screen 
welcomeLabel = Label (root, text="Hello user, welcome to the text input and calculator program")#Creates label widget 
welcomeLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)#Casts label to screen in specified position

textInputButton = Button(root, text="Text Input Mode", command=tiClick, fg='red')#adds button
textInputButton.grid(row=1, column=10)#Positions button 

calc = Button(root, text="Calculator Mode", command=calcClick, fg='red')#adds button
calc.grid(row=2, column=10)#Positions button   

def tiClick():
     tInputWindow = Toplevel()#opens a new window for the text input mode   
     tInputWindow.title("Text Input Mode")#Names the new window 

def calcClick():
    calcWindow = Toplevel()#opens a new window for Calculator mode   
    calcWindow.title("Calculator Mode")#Names the new window    

def button_add():
    return         

#Defines calculator buttons and places them in grid setting on screen
button_1 = Button(calcWindow, text="1", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=3, column=0)
button_2 = Button(calcWindow, text="2", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3 = Button(calcWindow, text="3", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=3, column=2)
button_4 = Button(calcWindow, text="4", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5 = Button(calcWindow, text="5", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6 = Button(calcWindow, text="6", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=2, column=2)
button_7 = Button(calcWindow, text="7", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=1, column=0)
button_8 = Button(calcWindow, text="8", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9 = Button(calcWindow, text="9", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=1, column=2)
button_0 = Button(calcWindow, text="0", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=4, column=0)  

root.mainloop()
```

The error pops up on the line were I add "button_1" and tells me "calcWindow" is not defined but "calcWindow" is defined as a new window with "Toplevel"

Comment: You should move those buttons creation inside `calcClick()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the button placement and calls inside the function calcClick()

```
def calcClick():
    calcWindow = Toplevel()#opens a new window for Calculator mode   
    calcWindow.title("Calculator Mode")#Names the new window   
    #Defines calculator buttons and places them in grid setting on screen
    button_1 = Button(calcWindow, text="1", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=3, column=0)
    button_2 = Button(calcWindow, text="2", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=3, column=1)
    button_3 = Button(calcWindow, text="3", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=3, column=2)
    button_4 = Button(calcWindow, text="4", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=2, column=0)
    button_5 = Button(calcWindow, text="5", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=2, column=1)
    button_6 = Button(calcWindow, text="6", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=2, column=2)
    button_7 = Button(calcWindow, text="7", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=1, column=0)
    button_8 = Button(calcWindow, text="8", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=1, column=1)
    button_9 = Button(calcWindow, text="9", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=1, column=2)
    button_0 = Button(calcWindow, text="0", padx=40, pady=20 , command=button_add).grid(row=4, column=0)
```

Comment: I did try that before but moved the definition under the buttons so it obv tried to access the window before it was defined lmao, cheers :)